# I am trying to destroy a gameobject after colliding with my player and then reinstantiate it to collide it again, forming a loop but it is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

//so basically this is the update function. All part of code is working. the only problem is my projectile is instantiated at first, after 1.5 seconds it is destroyed. After 2 seconds(the timebtwshots variable is set to 2) another projectile is instantiated but after 1.5 seconds, it is not deactivated. Thus, projectiles clutter up on my screen.

```
void Update()
{


    if (timebtwshots <= 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(blah());
        
    }
    else
    {
        timebtwshots -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    IEnumerator blah()
    {
        projectile.SetActive(true);
        Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        timebtwshots = starttimebtwshots;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        projectile.SetActive(false);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are only activating and deactivating the **prefab**, the original object, not the new created instance .. also do not put coroutines as nested methods under `Update` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where `projectile` is defined. Maybe a global object?

Anyway, when you Instantiate a new projectile, if you want to have control on it you have to assign it first to a variable.

`var spawnedProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);`

From that point, you can control THAT `spawnedProjectile`. In your code you're always accessing to the very first `projectile` thus the new ones are not disabled (you keep calling `.setActive(false)` on the projectile that has already active as false).

However, you're not destroying the object, you're just setting Active to false. You might consider using `Destroy(spawnedProjectile)` instead to entirely destroy the GameObject.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use `Instantiate` and `Destroy` for this at all! Look into [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling)